# React-Native Blur Radius Animation with ScrollView is Choppy

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, native

I have a ScrollView using Animated Event to do some basic animations. Everything works great but now I am wanting to animate blurRadius on images but the blur doesn't kick in until a few seconds after scrolling began. I've tried just about every animation solution possible...

This is the ScrollView... (AnimatedEvent.scrollYOffset is just a shortcut function I made) (Normally I have the throttle at 16 but found 7 was a little better but not even close to good)

```
        <ScrollView
        onScroll={AnimatedEvent.scrollYOffset(animY)}
        scrollEventThrottle={7}
        style={[QuickStyle.fillScreen,{
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(16, 50, 74)',
            flex: 1,
        }]}>
```

This is one of the images with the blur property...

```
    const blurry = this.state.animY.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0,150],
        outputRange: [0,7],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
    });

    const slide1 = <View style={[{
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(28, 181, 251)' //light blue
    }]}>
        <Animated.Image blurRadius={blurry} ref={img => this.blur1 = img} style={{
            width: width,
            height: height,
        }} source={require('../../assets/images/big-numbers.jpg')} />
    </View>;
```

What I've tried... (all with the same laggy choppy result) 1) Animating directly into the blurRadius prop 2) Using a ref with setNativeProps({blurRadius:x}) 3) Using setState({blurRadius:x}) - this was at least smooth but slowed down every animation a lot.

What I am trying next... Running these 3 solutions in release mode. I also will consider doing this directly in Objective-C, but really want to avoid that...

Would the react-native-blur package help? I'm guessing not...

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Still looking for a better answer. I am using native drivers... still no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave in and just put a BlurView from react-native-blur over what I wanted to blur. I then just animated the opacity and everything is smooth as can be.

The only problem is, it does not look as nice as blurring the image directly through blurRadius, but so far it's the only way I've been able to get this to work for now.

Please, if you have another solution, let me know!

**UPDATE**

Finally, I got this working without having to animate opacity on a react-native-blur BlurView! And it looks 10x better!

I am using the solution by @umitanuki from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur/issues/152

Here's how I did it...

1. Go to https://github.com/AlpacaDB/react-native-blur/tree/animate/ios
2. Set your BlurView.m in Xcode to exactly what the BlurView.m there has.
3. Use onScroll and setState to change the blurAmount property on a BlurView (react-native-blur).

This accomplishes the same effect as blurRadius but runs perfectly smooth when animating.

**EXTRA**

When using this solution I found one problem... When exiting the app and coming back to it (without fully quitting it), the blur goes away until you scroll again or do something to update it.

To solve this I went back into BlurView.m and added an observer for when the app becomes active...

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(appBecameActive)
                                                name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                              object:nil];
-(void) appBecameActive {
    [self updateBlurEffect];
}
```

I then ran updateBlurEffect when the app became active. Unfortunately there was no way to solve this within react-native, but this works perfectly.

Comment: Using `setState` to animate anything is not a good practice as it affects performance. It is recommended in that case to `useRef` instead. Just my 2 cents.